# SSRS passing Data Source credentials when deploying to SSRS Web Portal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I want certain reports to execute as a super user, but when I change the Credentials section for the .rdl embedded Data Sources, these changes do not propagate through to the web server.  That is, users still have to enter their username/password on the web server, and run into permissions issues.

The current workaround is to "Manage" the report on the web server (using the ellipses...) and telling each report to log into the data source "Using the following credentials..." and putting the super user creds.

But this means that everytime we redeploy the report, we need to do this.  We would prefer if the settings we have in the actual `.rdl` in `SSRS` actually show up on the web server after deployment.

Comment: How is the network configure? If you have Kerberos/AD or some variation thereof then you can may be able to specify no credentials as none are necessary..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use *shared datasources* for your reports. For each database a report needs access to, create one such *shared datasource*. The default project settings for Report Server projects in Visual Studio is to not overwrite datasources that already exist on the server when deploying the project. This way, you will have to set the credentials in the Web Portal for each datasource only once, and you don't have to care about that when deploying updated reports.